# Assigning element from first list to it's respective element in second list

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, list

I have a list of months(strings) & a list of image collections. I'd like to assign the value of each month's corresponding image collection to itself. How can I achieve this neatly without hardcoding?

[Script Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ad752bc99c3d909f689490ade7d20c4)

```
// filter ImageCollection 
var data = ic.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
             .filterBounds(region)
             .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10);

var listOfImages = data.toList(data.size());

// month names for ImageCollections to be created
var months = ["JAN_IC", "FEB_IC", "MAR_IC", "APR_IC", 
              "MAY_IC", "JUN_IC", "JUL_IC", "AUG_IC", 
              "SEP_IC", "OCT_IC", "NOV_IC", "DEC_IC"];
          
var monthsequence = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var monthlysubsets = monthsequence.map(function (month) {
    return listOfImages.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
});

// method to iterate over "monthlysubsets" to create 
// ImageCollection for each month from the list of "months"
// to achieve collections like in below instead of hardcoding
var JAN_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(0));
var FEB_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(1));
var MAR_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(2));
var APR_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(3));
var MAY_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(4));
var JUN_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(5));
var JUL_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(6));
var AUG_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(7));
var SEP_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(8));
var OCT_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(9));
var NOV_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(10));
var DEC_IC = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthlysubsets.get(11));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably best to use a dictionary in this case.

```
var m = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(months, monthlysubsets)
print(ee.List(m.get("JAN_IC")))
```

Access to the variable is a bit convoluted but also not too bad.

Depending on what you want to do with the data later, you could also think about having a list of ImageCollections where for each ImageCollection you just set a property `month` to the corresponding value in `months`.